# export table data in csv formate and store in folder

Tags: php

How To Do This In PHP ?

i wan't to export only table data in csv file and store csv file in backup folder.

for this i am using this :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `login_details`";
$file_name = "login_details";
$sql_csv = mysql_query($query) or die("Error: " . mysql_error()); //Replace this line with what is appropriate for your DB abstraction layer

header("Content-type:text/octect-stream");
$done = header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$fileName");

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql_csv)) {
     print '"' . stripslashes(implode('","',$row)) . "\"\n";
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should take a look at [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.fputcsv.php)

Answer (score 0):

you must open file to write (handle) use http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

use created handle to write string http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

close handle when done(see doc for fopen) use fclose()

for example:

```
//you code to get data from sql
$handle = fopen('full path to store (you can use ftp etd)', 'w'); // see mode
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql_csv)) {
     fputcsv($handle, $row);
}
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your backup folder is located (or can be located) on the same machine on which MySql is running then the fastest and simplest way to achieve your goal is to use [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html) clause

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM login_details
  INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/backup/folder/login_details.csv' 
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' -- or \r\n
```

php code

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
          FROM login_details
          INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/backup/folder/login_details.csv' 
               FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
               LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); //TODO better error handling
}
```

On a side note: `mysql_*` extension is deprecated. Consider switching to mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

you can use *fputcsv* to do this. here are function manual:http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `login_details`";
$file_name = "login_details";
$sql_csv = mysql_query($query) or die("Error: " . mysql_error()); //Replace this line with what is appropriate for your DB abstraction layer

$fp = fopen('cvsfile.csv', 'w');
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql_csv)) {
     fputcsv($fp, split(',', $row));
}
fclose($fp);
```